# how to print grand total from an array inside the main

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct EmployeeData
{
    string employeeName;
    float overtime;
    float grossPay;
    float hoursWorked;
    float hourlyRate;
    float statetaxOwed;
    float statetaxRate;
    float fedtaxOwed;
    float fedtaxRate;
    float netPay;
    float totalgp;
    float totalft;
    float totalst;
    float totalnp;
};

EmployeeData employee[4]; //array of 4 employees
void calculate_stats(EmployeeData& employee);

int main()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
    cout << "Please enter Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s" << " name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, employee[i].employeeName);
    cout << "Please enter Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s hours worked: ";
    cin >> employee[i].hoursWorked;
    cout << "Please enter Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s hourly rate: ";
    cin >> employee[i].hourlyRate;
    cout << "Please enter Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s Federal Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> employee[i].fedtaxRate;
    cout << "Please enter Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s State Tax Rate: ";
    cin >> employee[i].statetaxRate;
    cout << endl;
    }

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
    calculate_stats(employee[i]);

    cout << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed;
    cout << "Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s name is: " << employee[i].employeeName << endl;
    cout << "Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s Gross Pay is: $" << employee[i].grossPay << endl;
    cout << "Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s Federal Taxes owed is: $" << employee[i].fedtaxOwed << endl;
    cout << "Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s State Taxes owed is: $" << employee[i].statetaxOwed << endl;
    cout << "Employee #" << (i+1) << "'s Net Pay is: $" << employee[i].netPay << endl;
    cout << endl;
    }

cout << "Total Gross Pay: " << employee[4].totalgp << endl; //here is the problem
cout << "Total Federal Tax Owed: " << employee[4].totalft<< endl;
cout << "Total State Tax Owed: " << employee[4].totalft<< endl;
cout << "Total Net Pay: " << employee[4].totalft << endl;

}

void calculate_stats(EmployeeData& employee)
{
    if (employee.hoursWorked>40) {
        employee.hoursWorked = ((employee.hoursWorked-40) * (1.5)) + 40;
    }
    else {
        employee.hoursWorked = employee.hoursWorked;
    }
    employee.grossPay = employee.hoursWorked * employee.hourlyRate;
    employee.fedtaxOwed = employee.grossPay * (employee.fedtaxRate/100);
    employee.statetaxOwed = employee.grossPay * (employee.statetaxRate/100);
    employee.netPay = (employee.grossPay - employee.fedtaxOwed- employee.statetaxOwed);
    employee.totalgp = employee.totalgp + employee.grossPay;
    employee.totalft = employee.totalft + employee.fedtaxOwed;
    employee.totalst = employee.totalst + employee.statetaxOwed;
    employee.totalnp = employee.totalnp + employee.netPay;
}
```

I was sure to include that cout block outside of the for-loops but still in the main. Using calculate stats did not change the output for me. The output is giving me all 0.00...they should be complete totals across all 4 Employees (so if the gross pay for all 4 employees is 1000, then the total gross pay should be 4000, which is a grand total which I accounted for in my calculations: `employee.totalgp = employee.totalgp + employee.grossPay;`. Here is what the output looks like (a snapshot of the wrong display, the rest works fine)...

```
Total Gross Pay: 0.00
Total Federal Tax Owed: 0.00
Total State Tax Owed: 0.00
Total Net Pay: 0.00
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: `employee[4]` doesn't exist. Accessing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: When I remove `[4]` from the variables, I get errors. And when I remove `employee[4].` from the variables I also get errors. If I cannot access it, what should I be accessing to get a total of all the Employee values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are printing out as zero mainly due to luck on your part. Your array, defined as `EmployeeData employee[4]` allows for access to `employee[0]` to `employee[3]`. Accessing `employee[4]` for your print is accessing memory beyond what was allocated for your array.

Beyond that, you store nothing at the memory location with your code, which is not such a bad thing. You do store each set of data twice in each record:

```
employee.totalgp = employee.totalgp + employee.grossPay;
employee.totalft = employee.totalft + employee.fedtaxOwed;
employee.totalst = employee.totalst + employee.statetaxOwed;
employee.totalnp = employee.totalnp + employee.netPay;
```

Each call to `calculate_stats` is storing the `global` values in different locations, defeating your attempt to have a cumulative count. You need to define a separate `EmployeeData` instance to store the accumulated totals, and write the values into that object.

Once you have a new structure in place to store your totals, change the above four lines in your existing `calculate_stats` method to update the global totals structure.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh I see...I will try doing that. I suspected I may need another struct.

Comment: Ok, so I create a `struct` called `EmployeeTotals` and put `totalgp, totalft, totalst and totalnp` in it. I created an initializer called `EmployeeTotals grandtotal;` and then I created a `void calculate_totals(EmployeeTotals& grandtotal)` followed by the first part of the calculation: `grandtotal.totalgp = grandtotal.totalgp + employee.grossPay;` However...it gives me an error underneath employee now. How else can I create a grand total if I can't access all the employee variables? I'm very confused. Thank you for the help....

Comment: @MichelleZ If you define your `grandtotal` instance at the same level as your array, you can access it directly in your current `calculate_stats` method as I described above.

Comment: I think I've tried just about everything. I tried `employee[4]`, `employee` (gave me an error) ...`employee[4]` with `grandtotal[4]` in the main. I even set the grandtotal instance before the main as `grandtotal[4]` and that didn't work either. I think I fundamentally do not understand what you're trying to say. I don't know what "defining grandtotal instance at the same level as your array means" ...I have it already defined as a line above the main as `EmployeeTotals grandtotal;`...not sure what I have to do...I am very confused...still...thank you

Comment: So what I think you're saying is take all of the grandtotal calculations and put them above the `main`? AKA I can scrap `void calculate_totals(EmployeeTotals& grandtotal)`?